# VS2010 Integration with Subversion

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, integration

I might be in the minority, but I really dislike how the Subversion client integrates into the Windows shell.  Is there a Subversion client that simply integrates into VS2010 and that's all and doesn't mess with the Windows shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Subversion Plugins for Visual Studio are there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453481/what-subversion-plugins-for-visual-studio-are-there)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try [Ankh-SVN](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fankhsvn.open.collab.net%2F&ei=6M5MTPnAPIjBcaPKxbkI&usg=AFQjCNGvStDS9dax4Ka96cs0i70nMKAjMg&sig2=Uc1HMfnjvmUPoELys5aiVw)  I have found that it works pretty good for me.

Comment: Same here. It works really well. Never had any issue with it, plus, it's free!

Answer (score 9):

Consider trying [AnkhSVN](https://web.archive.org/web/20230222181712/https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) - a Visual Studio source control provider for Subversion. It's got support for Visual Studio 2010, and all features are available within VS.

[image]
<sub>(source: [collab.net](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/images/welcome.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is one I know of. I haven't used it as I still prefer TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a small amount of time with ankhsvn (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), and it seems to work well.  But a quick google search will return other results for you.

Answer (score 1):

I quite like [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com/visualsvn/), but it is a commercial product. It requires TortoiseSVN to be installed, but you don't have to use it. You could just disable the Windows Explorer icon overlay and then it's as it's not even there. (If you really wanted to, you could probably get rid of the Explorer context menu somehow, too.)